# ICommand DependencyProperty PropertyChanged Callback

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

In my custom control I am trying to invoke a method (i.e. the PropertyChangedCallback) whenever my `ICommand` Dependency property is invoked.

I have the following dependency property with the PropertyChangedCallback method

```
  public static readonly DependencyProperty ActiveOutput1Property =
      DependencyProperty.Register("ActiveOutput1", typeof(ICommand),
          typeof(CustomAxis_IO),
          new PropertyMetadata((ICommand)null,
              new PropertyChangedCallback(OnOutput1Changed)
            ));

 private static void OnOutput1Changed(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        ;
    }
```

And I have this dependency property implemented in my control here

```
<Button Command="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent},Path=ActiveOutput1}"/>
```

Everytime the button is pressed it will invoke the `ICommand` property that is bound to the `ActivateOutput1` dependency property.  So I know that is working.  However, my PropertyChangedCallback, `OnOutput1Changed`, is only invoked when the application starts.  How do I get a callback everytime my `ICommand` dependency property (`ActivateOutput1`) is invoked?

Comment: Try to set `Mode=TwoWay`. Why don't just use `ICommand` interface? There is an event `CanExecuteChanged` which always get fired when `Command` is fired.

Comment: But you're not actually changing the ActivateOutput1 value. You're only invoking it. If you need a callback for when the method is called, you can try to create a private command that calls ActiveOutput1 and execute whatever you want

Comment: I am trying to change a color of an element inside the custom control when the `Command` is fired.  So I would like to keep the logic in the custom control... If I understand you correctly.

Comment: You're binding is against the `DependencyProperty` which will only change when the value of the `ActiveOutput1` changes not when the `Command` is invoked. `OnOutput1Changed` would only execute if you assigned a different instance of `ICommand` to `ActiveOutput1`. It is the `Execute(object)` member of `ICommand` that will execute each time the button is pressed.

Comment: @mrsargent That's right. OR you can create a custom implementation of the ICommand class that accepts the callback

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If understand what you are trying to achive, you are trying to run some logic after the button is clicked, and the command execution action finished.

---

### Simple Solution

Since it is your custom control, you have all the freedom to use events. So here are the steps:

1. **DON'T** register the command to the button. (Go with me on this)
2. Register on the *Click* event of the button you are interested in.
3. Upon Click, call the *Execute* method on your *ICommand* Dependency Property.
4. Complete the implementation of your *Click* handler with your own logic.

In this way, you have the FULL freedom to do what ever you want after the command was executed.

**!!!Note!!!** 
If you need to also bind the *CanExecute* to the *IsEnabled* property of the button, you can register to the ***CommandManager***.RequerySuggested event, which will fire each time something is changed in the UI. At this moment, execute the *CanExecute* of your *ICommand* Dependency Property, and put the returned boolean to the *IsEnabled* property in the button.

---

### Complecated Solution

Create your own, abstract, base command implementation. In general, in this implementation, you will have some abstract methods to override in any derived classes and some events that will fire in strategic places.

This solution needs a lot more explanation, so if the simple solution doesn't work for you, share it and I'll clarify the complecated solution.

Happy Coding! :)

Comment: That simple solution worked great!  Since it is all one custom control I am not worried about the closely coupled relationship with the click event.  Very nice.

Answer (score 1):

As I (and some others, too) said on the comments, the PropertyChangedCallback is only invoked when you modify the DependencyProperty's value. When you call the ICommand, you're only invoking it. Hence, the PropertyChangedCallback won't be called. You can try creating your own ICommand implementation. Something like this:

```
public class CallbackAfterExecutionCommand : ICommand
{
    private Action<IMyView> _callback;

    // You can set this property on the PropertyChangedCallback class
    public IMyView View
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public CallbackAfterExecutionCommand(Action<IMyView> callback)
    {
        _callback = callback;
    }

    public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        // If you want, you can implement something here
        return true;
    }

    public void Execute(object parameter)
    {
        try
        {
            // Do whatever you want here. But you can also pass the execution
            // logic through a parameter on the constructor

            _callback(View);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }       
    }
}
```